# How to iterate through data and create a new text file every nth entries

Tags: c#

I'm making a list of lines that need to be added to a .txt file (with tab delimitation). The text file needs to have a maximum of 500 entries plus a header.

Right now, I have this code, which is successfully iterating through my list and creating the text file with the header. If the file already exists, it appends the lines in my list without adding the header.

I can't quite figure out how to make a new file, add the header and add each line after my first file surpasses 500 entries.

Can you help me separate in 500 line files with headers? Thank you

This is the code I have so far:

```
var tab = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var line in textlinestoadd)
    {
        tab.AppendLine(line.ToString());
    }

    if (!File.Exists(textcsvpath))
    {
        string textheader = "Vendor\tDate\tInvoice\tPO\tTax\tTotal\tAcount\tType\tJobs\tClass" +        Environment.NewLine;
        File.WriteAllText(textcsvpath, textheader);
    }
    File.AppendAllLines(textcsvpath, textlinestoadd);
```

Comment: So if your starting file exists and contains 200 lines you should add only 300 lines before creating a new file?

Comment: Exactly. Or if it doesn't exist and I'm creating a new file, it should add the header and up to 500 entries.

Comment: And if you need to have more than one file how do you plan to name the second file?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good practice opportunity so I will leave the code part as exercise!

The basic idea is simple. Whenever you wrote 500 lines just reset and write to a new file

here is a high level pseudo code

```
Initialize StringBuilder sb
For each line do 
    Add line to sb

    if line count == 500 then 
        save to file
        reset sb
        reset line count
        update filename = next file
    end if
End For

//writes the last chunk if # of lines is not multiple of 500
if line count is not 0 then 
    save to file
end if
```

Comment: I appreciate it, this makes sense. Will try it out, I was mostly struggling with the logic

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this.

```
var tab = new StringBuilder();
int lineCount = 0;
string textheader = "Vendor\tDate\tInvoice\tPO\tTax\tTotal\tAcount\tType\tJobs\tClass" + Environment.NewLine;

if (File.Exists(textcsvpath)) {
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(textcsvpath);
    string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(textcsvpath);
    lineCount = fileContent.Length - 1; // assume the first line is the header
}

foreach (var line in textlinestoadd)
{
    tab.AppendLine(line.ToString());
    lineCount++;
    if (lineCount > 0 && lineCount % 500 == 0)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(textcsvpath))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(textcsvpath, textheader);
        }
        File.AppendAllText(textcsvpath, tab.ToString());
        tab.Clear();
        textcsvpath = "some-new-file-name";
    }
}
if (!File.Exists(textcsvpath))
{
    File.WriteAllText(textcsvpath, textheader);
}
File.AppendAllText(textcsvpath, tab.ToString());
```

You'll need to do something to determine the new file name as you add a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
const int limit = 500;
int iteration = 0;
string textHeader = "Vendor\tDate\tInvoice\tPO\tTax\tTotal\tAcount\tType\tJobs\tClass" + Environment.NewLine;

while(iteration * limit < textLinesToAdd.Count())
{
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, $"{fileName}.{iteration}", extension);
  IEnumerable<string> linesToAdd = textLinesToAdd.Skip(iteration++ * limit).Take(limit);
  File.Create(fullPath);
  File.WriteAllText(fullPath, textHeader);
  File.AppendAllLines(fullPath, linesToAdd);
}
```

Define that filename as `foo` and the extension as `bar`, and you'll get a sequence of files called `foo.0.bar`, `foo.1.bar`, `foo.2.bar` and so on.

Comment: *"If the file already exists, it appends the lines in my list without adding the header."*

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we want to create a file with the specified name, and then have some integer placed between the name and extension that increments every time a new file is created.

One way to do this would be to have a method that takes in a filePath string, a list of lines to write, a header string, and the maximum number of lines allowed per file. Then it could parse the directory of the file path, looking for a pattern related to the file name.

It would determine what the latest file name should be based on the contents of the directory and the number of lines in the last file that matches our pattern, then would write to that file until it was full, and then continue creating new files until the lines were all written.

Here's a sample class that can do that, where I added some helper methods to get a file's number, increment that number in the name, get the latest file from a directory, and write lines to the file. It also implements `IComparer<string>` so that we can pass it to `OrderByDescending` to easily sort the files we're interested in.

```
public class FileWriterHelper : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        // Compare null
        if (x == null) return y == null ? 0 : 1;
        if (y == null) return -1;

        // Compare count of parts split on '.'
        var xParts = x.Split('.');
        var yParts = y.Split('.');
        if (xParts.Length < 3) return yParts.Length < 3 ? 0 : -1;
        if (yParts.Length < 3) return 1;

        // Compare numeric portion
        int xNum, yNum;
        if (int.TryParse(xParts[1], out xNum) &&
            int.TryParse(yParts[1], out yNum))
        {
            return xNum.CompareTo(yNum);
        }

        // Unknown values
        return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    private static int? GetFileNumber(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)) return null;
        var fileParts = fileName.Split('.');
        int fileNum;
        if (fileParts.Length < 3 || !int.TryParse(fileParts[1], out fileNum)) return null;
        return fileNum;
    }

    private static string IncrementNumber(string fileName)
    {
        var number = GetFileNumber(fileName).GetValueOrDefault() + 1;
        var fileParts = fileName.Split('.');
        return $"{fileParts[0]}.{number}.{fileParts[fileParts.Length - 1]}";
    }

    private static string GetLatestFile(string filePath, int maxLines)
    {
        var fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

        var latest = Directory.GetFiles(fileDir, $"{fileName}*{fileExt}")
            .OrderByDescending(f => f, new FileWriterHelper())
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? filePath;

        return File.Exists(latest) && File.ReadAllLines(latest).Length >= maxLines
            ? Path.Combine(fileDir, IncrementNumber(Path.GetFileName(latest)))
            : latest;
    }

    public static void WriteLinesToFile(string filePath, string header, 
        List<string> lines, int maxFileLines)
    {
        while ((lines?.Count ?? 0) > 0 && maxFileLines > 0)
        {
            var latestFile = GetLatestFile(filePath, maxFileLines);
            if (!File.Exists(latestFile)) File.CreateText(latestFile).Close();
            var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(latestFile).Length;

            if (lineCount == 0 && header != null)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(latestFile, string.Concat(header, Environment.NewLine));
                lineCount = 1;
            }

            var numLinesToWrite = maxFileLines - lineCount;
            File.AppendAllLines(latestFile, lines.Take(numLinesToWrite));

            lines = lines.Skip(numLinesToWrite).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

That was a bit of work, but now to use it is really simple:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Generate 5000 lines to write
    var fileLines = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).Select(i => $"Line number {i}").ToList();

    // File path with base file name
    var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.csv";

    // This should create 10 files
    FileWriterHelper.WriteLinesToFile(filePath, 
        "HEADER: This should be the first line in each file.", fileLines, 500);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

If you run that once, it will create 10 files (because of the number of lines we're generating and the max number of lines per file we specified). And if you run it again, it will create 10 more, since we're using the same path and file name pattern, it recognizes the previous files that were in the location.

I'm sure it could use some work, but hopefully it's a start!